# Dashboards - dynamic and personalized filters

Tags: dashboard

Data is segregated among Eastern Europe + Russia + Eastern Asia + Japan
A dynamic dashboard is created to showcase the data; 19 components are there in 1 dynamic dashboard. 3 filters are created -

1. Opportunity Type - 2 types of opportunities
2. Country - Limit is 50
3. Distributors - Active channel partners from these 50 countries.

Due to this 50 filter values limitation, I've created 4 different dynamic dashboards. The second limitation is I cannot create inter-dependent filters meaning if I select the country = CROATIA then the next distributor filter needs to list distributors from CROATIA only. For all salesforce internal users data visibility is correct and all the 3 filters are working as expected.
Now, I've 2 questions -

1. I want to make this dynamic dashboard available to the channel partner users meaning partner users which are configured in salesforce under the "Partner User" license. The requirement is partner user should see his/her data only and not others.
2. In the Distributor filter I've added the channel partners specific to 50 countries so even in this filter the partner user needs to see his partner account name only and not others. Is it possible to hide other filter values?

Thank you in advance.
Neha

Comment: 1- Should be possible if the Partner User has access to everything (Dashboards -> folders -> reports ->  objects -> records...) 2- Out of the box, no. A crude workaround is to filter on ['current user' field on all reports](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338834&type=1) in your dashboard. (No filter on dashboard itself). The reporting complexity you're facing is definitely a stretch for what is available out of the box in Sales/Service Cloud. Take a look at CRM Analytics or Tableau.

Comment: one more question -