# Dashboards - dynamic and personalized filters based on logged-in user

Tags: dashboard, experience-cloud

We recently purchased Experience Cloud and made dashboards for our brand partners to view on the site. The dashboards are filtered, so there are universal reports on every dashboard that are filtered with a dashboard filter so the user can only see data from that report regarding their brand.

Unfortunately, they have the ability to mess with this dashboard filter picklist and choose "All" and see all the company's data between all of our brand partners. These filtered dashboards save so much time and will continue to save exponential amounts of time as the company grows, but we don't want our partners to be using this filter. My boss is telling me the only option is going to end up being recreating all of these dashboards with all custom reports. Just not ideal at all.

I don't know much of anything about CSS but I'm desperate for a solution to this and that is so far the most promising route but I don't know how to build CSS that will work in this specific scenario. I found CSS from other forum discussions that helped remove buttons on Experience Cloud itself, but it didn't work when I tried to use my limited knowledge to customize the code. And it may be different since the dashboards are within a component, but I don't really know.

): help

[image]

Comment: CSS alone won't work and even if CSS + JavaScript might be _theoretically_ possible, practically it's not an option. We've tackled this issue for our customers and commented on an [an identical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377688/dashboards-dynamic-and-personalized-filters) someone else asked. Bottom line: you can't personalize the filter by having only display the logged in partner's name. What you can do is [implement data security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security) for your brand partners.

Comment: ...this way a partner will be able to see only their data in dashboards and underlying reports.  Yes, they'll still be able to see names of other partners in the filter but they won't see the other partners' data. Ultimately if you can't have other partner names' in the filter, your boss is correct - you'll need separate dashboards. As we said in the comment in the other Q&A, you're approaching the limits of what's possible out of the box. For more sophistication, look at [Tableau](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/learn-about-tableau)

Comment: It's not a big deal to have brands seeing other brand's names, just for them to not see that data. But I don't know what permissions to manipulate to prevent them from that.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial linked above, create a sandbox as your testing environment and give it a shot. Feel free to post new question(s) if you get stuck.